# How to replace exist in Hive with two correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query that looks like this

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*)
FROM users u, posts p
WHERE u.id = p.owneruserid 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) as num
              FROM postlinks pl
              WHERE pl.postid = p.id
              GROUP BY pl.id
              HAVING num > 1) --correlated subquery 1
  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM comments c
              WHERE c.postid = p.id); --correlated subquery 2
GROUP BY u.id
```

I researched and read that in Hive `IN` or `EXIST` are not supported statements. I read that a workaround for this would be to use a `LEFT JOIN`. I have tried this but I am having trouble with the `GROUP BY u.id`. I read that this needs to be paired always with an aggregation function like `COUNT()` however I'm not sure how I can rewrite this query so as to get it to work. All the other examples I have seen online do not seem to be as complicated as this one.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you can convert them to `left join` or may be `left join` since they uses `exists` in both subquery.  Simply convert your subqueries to inline view and join them with original tables.

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*)
FROM users u
inner join  posts p on u.id = p.owneruserid 
left outer join (SELECT COUNT(*) as num, pl.postid postid
              FROM postlinks pl 
              GROUP BY pl.postid
              HAVING num > 1) pl ON pl.postid = p.id --correlated subquery 1 with left join 
left outer join (SELECT postid FROM comments c GROUP BY postid)c ON c.postid = p.id  --correlated subquery 2  with left join 
WHERE ( c.postid is not null AND pl.postid is not null)  -- this ensure data exists in both subquery 
GROUP BY u.id
```

With left join, there may be chance of duplicates, you can use group by in subqry2 to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot:) I believe you unintentionally left the WHERE in the first subselect. Once I got rid of that it worked fine

Comment: Youre right, it was a typo, thx for pointing it out.